# Why is every question I ask getting deleted?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates, deleted-questions

I've asked about five questions on this site, and I occasionally check back to see if there is an answer yet, but somebody has usually deleted it. They say it's because there are similar questions, but they're not the exact question that I'm asking.

I just find this very pointless, and a waste of my time. Who can I get a hold of to find out why my questions keep getting deleted? I thought they were pretty valuable questions that did not have answers like other people's questions.

What's the point of having a site to find out information, if everybody's just going to delete my questions?

Comment: I only see two questions on your account other than this one. One was closed as a duplicate, and the other was closed for needing more focus. Am I missing something or was five just an estimate?

Answer (score 8):

**If your questions are indeed different from existing questions, you can (and often have to) specify that**, and they won't be deleted.

These two questions are the only ones you seem to have asked:

- [Is it possible to complete dawnguard and vampire storyline in same game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370228/is-it-possible-to-complete-dawnguard-and-vampire-storyline-in-same-game)
  This was closed as a duplicate of [Can I finish both sides of the Dawnguard DLC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299263), and there is no indication of your question being significantly different from the duplicate. The answer given there is the only valid answer.
- [On Skyrim PS4 is the anything I should worry about if I download the unofficial Skyrim patch?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370233)
  This was closed for lacking focus. The titular question is clear enough, but you also seem to be asking after a possible reason for a quest not disappearing after having completed it. Hence the need for focus. You can simply edit in what it is exactly you want help with. You can also ask both questions in separate threads.

Apart from this, proper writing and being comprehensive (and not using caps to show your frustration) might prevent this in the future.

This is not applicable to your situation, but note that some questions will be closed as duplicates even if an answer for someone's particular case is not provided. That, however, is also why we welcome new answers to old questions.